# How do I go about adding a new job title to my resume for the same company, and do I even need to?

Tags: resume, united-states, title

I've been working as an **Animal Health Technician III** in the state of New York for the past 5 years for the same animal hospital.

I recently just took the VTNE which is a national exam for Veterinary Technicians to become licensed in the state in which they want to practice. So, my new job title at my place of work is **Licensed Veterinary Technician**.

I am staying with the same animal hospital that I've been working for but am looking for part time work in another department and want to keep my resume current.

For all intents and purposes, an Animal Health Technician does share very similar job tasks and responsibilities as a Licensed Veterinary Technician give or take some things that legally an Animal Health Technician cannot do but an LVT can, with the main difference coming down to the passing of the VTNE and becoming "Licensed".

On my resume, can I just change the title I've had for the past 5 years as Animal Health Technician III to Licensed Veterinary Technician since the skillset and responsibilities are virtually the same, or is that misleading? If I do have to separate the two, how do I go about doing that on my resume?

Answer (score 5):

List them as a sub heading. Example

```
2/2020-current: HappyDog, Inc, Catsville
  4/2023-current: licensed Vet tech
  2/2020-3/2023: lead fur scratcher
```

For employments that are more than 5 years in the past, you can simply lump it into a single line.

Comment: "**lead fur scratcher**" ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Looks like a joke to me

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Yeah, I know. That's a funny joke :-). I also love pets (cats/dogs), and appreciate what animal clinics can do for them.  BTW, How about "**Lead Paw Massage**" in addition to "**Lead fur scratcher**" :-) ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you can put both titles on your resume as follows:

Animal Health Technician III (**Licensed Veterinary Technician**)

Comment: That works for me. Feature the certification/licensing as an achievement rather than as just a title.

Answer (score 1):

Title isn't very significant in a resume. What you actually achieved matters far more. I wouldn't worry about it.

(Though I was pleased about being able to officially use the title "Scientist" when I was in the research division. That's what eight-year-old me wanted to be when he grew up Mumble decades later. I still don't know what I'm going to be when and if I grow up.)